# Partition of the long list

Tags: data, partitions

I am trying to do the partition of the list variable called
**test** so that answer will look like the variable called **goal**.  The **test** list is actually a list of long data.  In this example I have a short version example according to the code below which also includes my attempts called ans1 and ans2 using method called Partition and ArrayShape:

```
 Clear[ans];
 goal={{{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i},j},{{k,l,m},{n,o,p},{q,r,s},t}};
 TableForm[goal]
```

And the output should be

```
 a d g
 b e h j
 c f i

 k n q
 l o r t
 m p s
```

My attempt is:

```
 test={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t};
 ans1=Partition[test,3,3,1,Nothing]
 {{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i},{j,k,l},{m,n,o},{p,q,r},{s,t}}
 TableForm[ans1]

 ans2=ArrayReshape[test,{3,3,3},1]
 {{{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}},{{j,k,l},{m,n,o},{p,q,r}},{{s,t,1},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}}}
 TableForm[ans2]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit(reply to comment)**

For the pattern  `{{#,#,#},{#,#,#},{#,#,#},{#,#,#},#}`,there are `3*4+1` elements, so we use

```
test = Range[39];
FlattenAt[#, {-1}] & /@ (Partition[#, UpTo[3]] & /@ 
   Partition[test, UpTo[3*4 + 1]])
```

[image]

**Original**

```
test={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t};
FlattenAt[#, {-1}] & /@ (Partition[#, UpTo[3]] & /@ 
   Partition[test, UpTo[10]])

FlattenAt[#, {-1}] & /@ (Partition[#, UpTo[3]] & /@ 
   Partition[test, 10])

FlattenAt[#, {-1}] & /@ (Partition[#, 3, 3, 1, Nothing] & /@ 
   Partition[test, 10])
```

[image: > {{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}, j}, {{k, l, m}, {n, o, p}, {q, r, s}, t}}]

Comment: Great code.....How do you adjust from (3,3,1) to (3,4,1)?   Or originally 3 vectors (of 3variables) and scalar to 4 vectors (3 variables) and scalar. {{{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i},{j,k,l}},n},{{o,p,q},{........}}     when test list is long.

Comment: @Aschoolar  Use `FlattenAt[#, {-1}] & /@ (Partition[#, UpTo[3]] & /@ 
   Partition[test, UpTo[4*3 + 1]])`  Or `FlattenAt[#, {-1}] & /@ (Partition[#, 3, 3, 1, Nothing] & /@ 
   Partition[test, 4*3 + 1])`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the number of items in `test` is not divisible by the total number of elements in each partition, e.g.,

> ```
> test = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u,
>     v, w, x, y};
> ```

a possible solution using `TakeList` can be:

```
FlattenAt[#, {4}] & /@ (TakeList[#, UpTo /@ {3, 3, 3, 1}] & /@ 
   Partition[test, UpTo[10]])
```

> ```
> {{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}, 
>   j}, {{k, l, m}, {n, o, p}, {q, r, s}, t}, {{u, v, w}, {x, y}, {}}}
> ```